# How do I add a search bar to a search tab inside of my app in Swift Playgrounds (For iPad)?

Tags: ipad, swiftui

I want to add a search bar to my “Search Tab” in my Swift Playgrounds app (SP for iPad on iPad Pro).

I tried anything I could find and nothing worked.[What it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp2bB.png)
I want it to look like the image, except there’s a search bar there.

```
            VStack {
                Text("Line 1")
                Text("Line 2")
                Text("Line 3")
            }
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("Search")
                }
            }
            .tag(6)
```

I just don’t have much to say, so this might look dumb.